# getActionBar( ) null in activity under a tabHost

Tags: android

I create a tab with tabHost , under each tab is a activity :
MainActivity.class

```
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); 

    this.setNewTab(this, tabHost, "tab1", R.drawable.icon_blackberry_config, new Intent().setClass(this, HiepActivity.class));
    this.setNewTab(this, tabHost, "tab2", R.drawable.icon_windows_config,new Intent().setClass(this, BlackBerryActivity.class));
    this.setNewTab(this, tabHost, "tab3",  R.drawable.icon_apple_config,new Intent().setClass(this, AppleActivity.class));
    this.setNewTab(this, tabHost, "tab4",  R.drawable.icon_android_config,new Intent().setClass(this, AndroidActivity.class));
    tabHost.getTabWidget().setStripEnabled(false);

    tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
}
 private void setNewTab(Context context, TabHost tabHost, String tag, int icon, Intent in ){
        TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(tag);
        tabSpec.setIndicator(getTabIndicator(tabHost.getContext(), icon)); // new function to inject our own tab layout
        tabSpec.setContent(in);
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
    }

 private View getTabIndicator(Context context, int icon) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tab_layout, null);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        iv.setImageResource(icon);
        return view;
    }
```

And under HiepActivity, I want show a Swipe tab with fragment :

```
public class HiepActivity extends Activity  implements ActionBar.TabListener  {

// Declaring our tabs and the corresponding fragments.
ActionBar.Tab bmwTab, fordTab, toyotaTab;
Fragment bmwFragmentTab = new TopRatedFragment();
Fragment toyotaFragmentTab = new GamesFragment();
Fragment fordFragmentTab = new TopRatedFragment();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    setContentView(R.layout.hieptab);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
     Log.v("error", actionBar+"");
```

But is always null when call getActionBar() in HiepActivity .
All I want is under a tabhost activity (MainActivity) have a swipetab inside (HiepActivity) .Why and How to resolve that ? Thank you.
**Update :**
I found that it because the MainActivity is use actionbar so the HiepActivity dont have ActionBar.So its impossible to solve thí .Thank you so much.

Comment: getActionBar is not resolved in your app, think may not be using the correct theme in manifest, and one more thing use AppcompatActivity if possible.

Comment: I've tried change the theme but is still error

Comment: Main thing is that you should also use getSupportActionBar()

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the context of current class try to use class context .getActionBar()

Comment: I think so,the MainActivity is use the actionbar so the activity in tabhost in MainActivity can't use the action bar.But how to solve that ?

Comment: Can you try: this.getActionBar()